# Cannot require 'rmagick' despite normal installation on Ubuntu (LoadError: no such file to load -- rmagick)

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I have installed all the dev files (`sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev`) as well as the gem itself (`gem install rmagick`), and everything installed just fine, no compilation or installation errors in either steps.

The problem occurs whenever I actually `require 'rmagick'`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'rmagick'
LoadError: no such file to load -- rmagick
  from /home/marfay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from /home/marfay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from (irb):1
  from /home/marfay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I have tried numerous ruby installs of different version on rvm, as well as system installs using aptitude, everything failed at `require` with the same error message.

Any guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=306216

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. Still same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `RMagick` instead of `rmagick`:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'RMagick'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> puts Magick::Long_version
This is RMagick 2.13.1 ($Date: 2009/12/20 02:33:33 $) Copyright (C) 2009 by Timothy P. Hunter
Built with ImageMagick 6.6.8-5 2011-07-08 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Built for ruby 1.8.7
Web page: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org
Email: rmagick@rubyforge.org
=> nil
irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: Wow...just wow...